# Do the results from hypothesis testing follow triangle inequality?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics

Firstly, please note that my question could be wrongly written. So I am explaining my problem here more clearly. I will edit the question once I get the appropriate terms.

I have 3 methods to perform a task and the outcome is to minimize the objective. I repeat each method N(>30) number of times and record the outcome. Let the methods be A, B and C. Now if A is significantly better than B, with some statistical test X. And B is significantly better than C, then is it necessary that A is significantly better than C? If so then what is it called mathematically?

Furthermore, does this property depend on X?

Comment: Should I ask this in mathematics?

Comment: In your last comparison do you mean better than C?

Comment: Yes. Corrected. I am making the change.

Comment: The property is called transitivity I believe.

Comment: The mathematical term for the assertion "$A\,\mathcal{R}\,B$ and $B\,\mathcal{R}\,C$ imply $A\,\mathcal{R}\,C$" for a relation $\mathcal{R}$ (such as "is significantly better than") is *transitivity*.  However, it's unclear what you are asking, because "minimize the objective" is definitely not a hypothesis test, whereas "is significantly better than" sounds like the conclusion of a hypothesis test.  If you could be more specific or clearer about your situation, then we might be able to help.

Comment: @whuber Looks to me like OP just wants to know whether statistical significance is always transitive. The bit about "minimizing an objective" seems to just be a vague reference to where OP's actual data came from; I don't think OP is asking about optimization problems.

Comment: @Kodiologist Thank you for attempting a clarification.  I would be glad to reopen the thread after the OP modifies it to address these ambiguities.